# Llenar una matriz en java desde una posición inicial hasta una final

Tags: java, array, matrices, bucles

Si tengo una matriz por ejemplo:

```
String matriz[][]= new String[4][5];
```

Y quiero llenar dicha matriz tal y como se muestra en la imagen usando ciclos, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?, ya intenté muchas cosas y aún no lo logro[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega que código has hecho en tuds intentos, tal vez así te podamos ayudar a detectar por qué no obtubiste los resultados que esperabas

Answer (score 1):

El enfoque que yo tomaría, dado que no hay un patrón claro para poder, de manera programática, describir la asignación de los valores de la matriz, sería realizar un loop
con cada uno de los casos en los que se debe llenar la matriz.

```
for(int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
    if(i == 0 || i == 3) continue;
    for(int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++){
        if(i == 1 && j != 0){
            matriz[i][j] = "a";
        }
        else if(i == 2 && (j == 0 || j == 1)){
            matriz[i][j] = "a";
        }
    }   
}
```